# Does repast allow floating point coordinates for agents?

Tags: simulation, modeling, repast-simphony

Netlogo allows floating point coordinates for an agent that is on a patch that has integer coordinates. I would like to be able to do the same in repast.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Repast does this through projections, where agents can be part of a grid and a continuous space projection at the same time. For more details take a look at [Grid](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastReference/RepastReference.html#_grid_projections) and [Continuous Space](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastReference/RepastReference.html#_continuous_space_projection) projection sections of the [Repast Reference](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastReference/RepastReference.html) document.

The [Repast Java Getting Started](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastJavaGettingStarted.pdf) and the [ReLogo Getting Started](https://repast.github.io/docs/ReLogoGettingStarted.pdf) Guides would be helpful as well.